# Vue communicate between unrelated components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a navbar component that I'm rendering on App.js. I have some product cards with a quick add button on another page. I want to add a cart icon on the navbar which will increase count every time I add a product from the product card. However, since they are not parent-child or siblings, I'm unsure about how to pass the data from the product card to the navbar here. Any examples will be really helpful.

Comment: you can use Vuex (for vue2)/Pinia (for vue3) to manage your global data, or use `$root.$emit` and `$root.$on` to communicate between unrelated components easily ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315823/10519069))

Comment: @DengSihan Pinia is available for 2 as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the playground with a custom store.

Check also the answer [How to pass a reactive variable...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75566693/2487565) for details.

```js
const { createApp, ref, toRef, toRefs } = Vue;

const myStore = {
  counter: ref(0),
  add: function() {
    this.counter++ 
  }   
}

const Basket = {
  setup() {
    const { counter, add } = myStore
    return  { counter, add }
  },
  template: 'counter = {{counter}}&nbsp;<button @click="add()">+1</button>' 
}

const App = {
  components: { Basket },
  setup() {
    const { counter, add } = myStore
    return  { counter, add }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Basket: <basket></basket><br/>
  App: counter = {{counter}}&nbsp; <button @click="add()">+1</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution with Pinia

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia

const useStore = defineStore('currentDocument', 
{
  state: () => {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  actions: {
   add() { this.$state.counter++ }
  }
})

const Basket = {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const { counter } = storeToRefs(store)  
    return {
      store,
      counter
    }
  },
  template: 'counter = {{counter}}&nbsp;<button @click="store.add()">+1</button>' 
}

const App = {
  components: { Basket },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    const { counter } = storeToRefs(store)  
  return {
      store,
      counter
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const pinia = createPinia()
app.use(pinia)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Basket: <basket></basket><br/>
  App: counter = {{counter}}&nbsp; <button @click="store.add()">+1</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi@0.13.11/lib/index.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia@2.0.30/dist/pinia.iife.js"></script>
```